# Ошибка в MsSql после перезапуска

Tags: sql, sql-server

После перезапуска сервера не могу выполнить запросы на данные, которые были записаны сегодня.

Например:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM table 
WHERE date = '20170816' -- вчерашняя дата
```

Работает нормально

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM table 
WHERE date = '20170817' -- сегодняшняя дата
```

Выдаёт ошибку

`Сообщение 601, уровень 12, состояние 3, строка 1
Не удалось продолжить просмотр с NOLOCK вследствие перемещения данных`

тип поля `date datetime`

Не могу понять, в чем может быть ошибка и откуда начать.

Comment: Приложите текст ошибки.

Comment: А заодно и структуру таблицы (хотя бы тип поля `date`).

Comment: мне кажется таблица сломалась. Попробуйте сделать repair штатными средствами.

Comment: Сделал `dbcc checktable` и в таблицах где выходили ошибки перестраивал индексы и проверял ушла ли ошибка если нет то делал `repair_rebuild`. Но после этого некоторые данные сбились и пришлось в ручную исправлять неправильные данные.